# Checking if the record saved in JS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

Using a standard `update` action combined with a `remote` form, the user submits a small chunk of data via AJAX, which gets sent to the action as javascript, and the response is rendered in javascript using `format.js`.

```
def update
  @message = Message.where("recipient_id = ? AND id = ?", current_user.id, params[:id]).first
  respond_to do |format|
    if @message.update_attributes(params[:message])
      format.html { redirect_to(@message, :notice => 'Message updated.') }
      format.xml  { head :ok }
      format.js
    else
      format.html { render :action => "edit" }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @message.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

This generates a JS file called `update.js.erb`, which I use to render text and effects to show the user whether the action was successful.

**How can I check in update.js.erb whether that record saved or not?**

At the moment, I'm doing a supremely inelegant `@success = true` in the controller, which I test in the js.erb file to decide what text/effects to render. There must be a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi what about using this:

```
<% if @message.errors.empty? %>
  SUCCESS
<% else %>
  FAIL_CODE
<% end %>
```

I hope this helps.